# How to build libcpr/cpr static library using mingw?

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, mingw, mingw-w64

I'm trying to build [libcpr/cpr](https://github.com/libcpr/cpr) on Windows with Mingw64 and the output is always a `libcpr.dll libcurl-d.dll libzlib.dll` file in the `./lib` folder.

How can make the build provide a lib file instead of dll files?

Comment: Why are you asking here, instead of on the project issues page or wherever the project gets support?  There's no _generic_ way to do it, you have to find out if and how the project supports it.

Comment: @JesperJuhl please excuse me. I'm new to C++, I basically want the compiled binary to not use dll files and have the dependencies. Are shared libraries not dynamic linking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CMake flag `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF` to build static library files (`*.a`).

Comment: I'm basically using the following commands: `cmake .. -G "Mingw Makefile" && mingw32-make` I also tried adding the flag, but it still builds dll files.

Comment: Make sure to delete the files from your previous attempts and start fresh.
I was using MSYS2 shell using a command like this `cmake.exe -G"MSYS Makefiles" -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF .. && make`

Comment: Thanks a Lot! That worked. I was using `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF` instead and it wasn't working. Also if you wont mind, would you please explain what might the difference if i not put `:BOOL`.

Comment: The `:BOOL` shouldn't make a difference really. But cleaning up the files left over from previously running CMake should make a difference.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)

Oh, As a matter of fact i just realized you're the dev of winlibs :D I actually tried building on winlibs first with curl headers and binaries, but it didn't work, so i changed to msys :(

Comment: @CypherpunkSamurai Actually curl does build with https://winlibs.com/ when the dependencies are built in the same environment. It's not a very good idea to mix compiler versions in one build.